# different output running py on terminal and on vscode

Tags: python, conda, virtualenv

```
import os
import spacy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
print('ok')
```

Running “Python main.py” on iterm terminal

```
ok
```

Running “Python main.py” on vscode terminal

```
(base) thiagoleobons@Thiagos-MacBook-Pro taylor % conda activate wordcloudpy
(wordcloudpy) thiagoleobons@Thiagos-MacBook-Pro taylor % python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/thiagoleobons/Downloads/software/ml/taylor/main.py", line 2, in \<module\>
import spacy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'
(wordcloudpy) thiagoleobons@Thiagos-MacBook-Pro taylor % conda list spacy

# packages in environment at /Users/thiagoleobons/miniconda3/envs/wordcloudpy:

# 

# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

spacy                     3.5.2            py39h04adbd3_0    conda-forge
spacy-legacy              3.0.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
spacy-loggers             1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python -m spacy validate
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named spacy
(wordcloudpy) thiagoleobons@Thiagos-MacBook-Pro taylor % /Users/thiagoleobons/miniconda3/envs/wordcloudpy/bin/python -m spacy validate
✔ Loaded compatibility table

================= Installed pipeline packages (spaCy v3.5.2) =================
ℹ spaCy installation:
/Users/thiagoleobons/miniconda3/envs/wordcloudpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy

NAME             SPACY            VERSION  
en_core_web_sm   \>=3.5.0,\<3.6.0   3.5.0   ✔
```

The following suggestions have already been tried for the mismatch between the output on vscode x output on iterm:

1. Create settings.json on .vscode folder with content:

```
   {
   "python.pythonPath": "/Users/thiagoleobons/miniconda3/envs/wordcloudpy/env/bin/python"
   }
```

2. Change the following settings on VScode user settings.json:

```
   "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
   "PATH": "/Users/thiagoleobons/miniconda3/envs/wordcloudpy/env/bin:${env:PATH}"
   },
   "python.pythonPath": “/Users/thiagoleobons/miniconda3/envs/wordcloudpy/env/bin/python”,
   "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
   "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
   "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": “iTerm",
```

3. Create .env on VSCode with content:

```
   PYTHONPATH=/Users/thiagoleobons/miniconda3/envs/wordcloudpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

4. Create last line on .zshrc:

```
   export PATH=“/Users/thiagoleobons/miniconda3/envs/wordcloudpy/env/bin:$PATH”
```

5. adding following line to beginning of main.py and .zshrc:

```
   \#!/Users/thiagoleobons/miniconda3/envs/wordcloudpy/bin/python
```

None of the solutions above fixed it. Keep in mind:

- Status bar on vscode shows Python 3.9.16 ('wordcloudpy': conda)
- Selecting interpreter on command palette also shows the same interpreter being used
- Vscode terminal shows wordcloudpy env activated (output above).
  The error suggests there’s no spacy lib installed but running conda list spacy shows the lib is installed(output above)

Still running code on iterm terminal prints OK but shows error on VSCode terminal. What can be causing the issue?
The only thing that worked was running this whole path /Users/thiagoleobons/miniconda3/envs/wordcloudpy/bin/python main.py How can I achieve this by running only python main.py?

The following command was used to create wordcloudpy env:

```
conda create --name wordcloudpy python=3.9
```

But running python —version on this environment returns `Python 3.11.2` (but returns `Python 3.9.16` on iTerm).

Been trying to debug this for hours. ><

listed above in excruciating detail